# wifi chat on android

Tags: android, chat, wifi

Is Wifi chat is possible on android?

My requirement is my Pc thats connected with a wifi dongle and my android device has wifi. I want to convert my pc to server and android device to client and implement the chat.

Is this possible?

Please help me out.

Comment: Probably, but this is a bit broad to cover in one question and answer. Do you have a specific question?

Comment: I think it is *possible*. If you look at the android market there are apps like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously it's possible. To start with, you could make a peer-to-peer chat over UDP, hard-coding each other's IP numbers into the other's programs. A few lines of python on the PC, a few lines of Java on the Android. Then you could start adding the functionality you need to make it client-server: add a broadcast listener on the PC, so that it can auto-detect clients, then you can eliminate the schlock hard-coded IP numbers. And build up from there.

---

Example server-side in Python:

```
jcomeau@intrepid:/usr/src/xmlvm.svn$ python
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Dec 27 2010, 00:02:40) 
[GCC 4.4.5] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import socket
>>> chatter = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
>>> chatter.bind(('192.168.1.121', 9999))
>>> chatter.sendto('this is a test', ('192.168.1.144', 6666))
14
```

Comment: hi jcomeau can more give more detail ans for that!

Comment: @milind, sure, if I had the time and the inclination, but I've currently got a paying job that takes preference.

Comment: hi jcomeau_ictx thanks very much for tha reply.... Can you give any simple code example for this application please....